# How do I recursively call bind_rows from dplyr on a list of lists of data.frames?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of lists of lists of `data.frames` in `R`, which I would like to bind together.  Here's an example:

```
tmp <- list(
    list(
        list(
            data.frame(x = 1:5),
            data.frame(x = 6:10)
            ),
        list(
            data.frame(x = 11:15),
            data.frame(x = 16:20)
            )
    ),
    list(
        list(
            data.frame(x = 21:25),
            data.frame(x = 26:30)
            ),
        list(
            data.frame(x = 31:35),
            data.frame(x = 36:40)
            )
        )
    )

bind_rows(
    bind_rows(lapply(tmp[[1]], bind_rows)),
    bind_rows(lapply(tmp[[2]], bind_rows))
    )
```

Clearly this is a mess, so I was hoping there was a better way.  Maybe there's some way to recursively call `bind_rows` so that it keeps going down levels of the list until it finds a `data.frame` to bind?

Comment: hadley's purrr package has a `flatten` function, though I haven't used it.

Comment: I was playing with flatten. `flatten(tmp) %>% flatten %>% bind_rows` would be one way to go.

Comment: Hmm, isn't this just `data.frame(x = unlist(tmp))` for your example case?

Comment: @jazzurro So far, repeatedly calling `flatten` seems to be the least ugly solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `collapse` package has a function for this:

```
library(collapse)
unlist2d(tmp, idcols = F) 

# Or if you want add add an ID column for each list level
unlist2d(tmp)
```

Or an alternative to your answer using `dplyr` ... which is still ugly:

```
tmp %>%
  lapply(bind_rows) %>%
  lapply(bind_rows) %>%
  lapply(bind_rows) %>%
  bind_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Reduce(dplyr::bind_rows, unlist(unlist(tmp, FALSE), FALSE)) 

#Source: local data frame [40 x 1]
#
#       x
#   (int)
#1      1
#2      2
#3      3
#4      4
#5      5
#6      6
#7      7
#8      8
#9      9
#10    10
#..   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this function::

```
bind_rows <- function(lst){
    if(class(lst[[1]]) == "data.frame") {
        return(data.table::rbindlist(lst))
    } else {
        bind_rows(unlist(lst, recursive = FALSE))
    }
}
```